# Styling Identity Scaffolded Razor Pages to use default Blazor theme

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I just added Identity to my existing Blazor Server project using Identity Scaffolding.
I followed this Microsoft learn guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-a-blazor-server-project).

However, since Identity uses Razor pages instead of Razor components, the styling of the UI changes when a visitor navigates between Identity pages and components.

For eg: The page initially loads like this:
[image]

And when the user hits the `Login` link at the top right corner, the login page opens which looks so ugly :
[image]

To fix that, I tried to follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-a-custom-layout-with-blazor-app-styles) at Microsoft learn.
But I'm hit with this error ([code link here](https://github.com/affableashish/blazor-server-auth/blob/7d6e78a7442ddb7364a03427d3c0a7eb3813e153/src/HMT.Web.Server/Features/Shared/Layout/_Layout.cshtml#L27)) :

```
The name 'Engine' does not exist in the current context
```

---

Can someone please guide me in the right direction for styling Identity Razor Pages in Blazor to get a consistent look and feel with rest of the app? Microsoft learn guide seems to be lacking.

Comment: I've created it as an Issue in aspnetcore's GitHub page. Check it out if you're interested: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation totally misses these 2 lines that need to be added to the top of `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines
@inject ICompositeViewEngine Engine
```

Adding those lines resolved the error.

However, I **didn't** even go that route at the end.

---

**If you're interested in my complete solution, this is what I ended up doing:**

In summary, I took *MainLayout.razor* and put it inside _*Layout.cshtml*.

If the steps mentioned below are hard to follow, take a look at the code. The full source code is [here](https://github.com/akhanalcs/blazor-server-auth/tree/feature/LayoutWithIdentityPages).

### Demo

Unauthorized View
[image]

Login Page
[image]

Authorized View
[image]

### Step 1:

Since we're using *NavMenu* and *LoginDisplay* razor components inside _*Layout.cshtml*, add these to the top of _*Layout.cshtml*:

```
@using HMT.Web.Server.Features.Shared.Layout.NavMenu
@using HMT.Web.Server.Features.Identity
```

### Step 2:

Replace `<body>` with this:

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <component type="typeof(NavMenu)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
        </div>

        <main>
            <div class="top-row px-4 logindisplay">
                <component type="typeof(LoginDisplay)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
            </div>

            <article class="content px-4">
                @RenderBody()
            </article>

            <div class="bottom-row px-4">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="/images/logo-black.png" width="40"/>
                    <span class="fs-4">HMT</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div id="blazor-error-ui">
                <environment include="Staging,Production">
                    An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
                </environment>
                <environment include="Development">
                    An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
                </environment>
                <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
                <a class="dismiss"></a>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>

    <script src="~/Identity/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Identity/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
```

If you're thinking that I just cut and pasted `<div class="page">`  section from *MainLayout.razor*, you're absolutely right.

### Step 3:

Create:
*Features/Shared/Layout/**_Layout.cshtml.css*** file.
Now cut and paste all the *css* styles from your *MainLayout.razor.css* to _*Layout.cshtml.css*.
For reference, [this is how](https://github.com/akhanalcs/blazor-server-auth/blob/feature/LayoutWithIdentityPages/src/HMT.Web.Server/Features/Shared/Layout/_Layout.cshtml.css) mine looks like.

### Step 4:

All that remains inside *MainLayout.razor* is this:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<PageTitle>Handy Man's Tool</PageTitle>
@Body
```

### Step 5:

Wrap `AuthorizeView` in *LoginDisplay.razor* with `<CascadingAuthenticationState>`.
The reason is that if you try to use a Razor Component that has `Authorize` components from component that IS NOT
wrapped with `<CascadingAuthenticationState>`, it won't work,
That is the reason why `<component type="typeof(LoginDisplay)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />` doesn't work in _*Layout.cshtml* without it.

### Step 6:

If you want to protect the NavLinks in *NavMenu*, wrap them inside `AuthorizeView`, and since *NavMenu* is rendered
from _*Layout.cshtml*, don't forget to wrap them inside `<CascadingAuthenticationState>`.
For eg: Mine looks like this:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <nav class="flex-column">
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                    <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            <AuthorizeView>
                <div class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                        <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
            </AuthorizeView>
        </nav>
    </div>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

### Step 7:

Remove the following files as they're unnecessary:

1. Areas/Identity/Pages/_*ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml* (as I'm not overriding it.)
2. Features/Shared/Layout/_*ViewImports.cshtml*
3. Features/Shared/Layout/_*LoginPartial.cshtml* (Using *LoginDisplay* instead)

### Full source code

https://github.com/akhanalcs/blazor-server-auth/tree/feature/LayoutWithIdentityPages

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same solution... but with .NET 8 you can use [Blazor Identity UI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-with-identity-in-dotnet-8/#the-blazor-identity-ui) which includes options to register, log in, and configure multi-factor authentication.

You wouldn't need to [do Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-a-razor-project-with-authorization) in the server project, on new project select *"Authentication type": Individual Accounts*

[image]

Same result more simple ;D

[image]